CSS Flexbox justify-content Space Between Only Some Items?
I have a div where I want to apply justify-content: space-between but have the first 2 or last 2 (or whatever combination I need) of items "stick together".
For example if I have a Navigation menu, the menu will obviously be wider than icons I want to put in the same div.  So if that div has 4 items, Nav and 3 social media icons, and I apply space-between, those icons sort of float in the middle on the right side.  I want them to be grouped to the right and that space between the wider nav and the grouping of 3 icons flow nice.  I don't want to do this by putting them in yet another div.  Is this possible?  Is there a style I can add to the 3 icons I want on the right?
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/
In this case, I would want the green boxes to be [1][2] . . . [3][4][5] if that makes sense.

Please see [ask]. You're expected to show code. You can easily create a demo snippet with the editor.

Does this answer your question? flexbox space-between and align right

@isherwood Not quite because that seems to only apply the align-right to a single item using :last-child.  I'm not sure how to set up a demo snippet but I will try, give me a few and let me edit the question.

Well, it's easy enough to wrap those two in a container div which will be aligned as you describe.

@RodeoRamsey The same principle applies, apply margin-left: auto on the first item you want to push to the right. (or margin-right:auto to the last item you want on the left. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QWRORom

try setting the margin left or right on the deviding element like this:


.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: #1565C0;
}

 
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li style="margin-left:auto"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



